# Sbt error (requires least version of java)

Tags: java, scala, sbt

Sbt is giving me an error:

```
The Java Development Kit (JDK) installation you have is not up to date. sbt requires at least version 6+, you have version 0
```

But I have the latest version of Java.

Comment: I don’t know anything about sbt but because it says it’s finding java 0, I’d imagine it’s not finding any jdk on your machine.

Comment: What version of sbt are you using? What operating system are you on? Please describe the problem in a way that others can reproduce it.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Try to open your cmd or terminal and check if you have Java with `java --version`, `javac --version`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is another bug in sbt with the Windows build. There was an [issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/4055) opened that intended to fix this in the latest sbt release (1.1.4), however it does not appear it actually fixed the issue.